# checking for a version of the software using makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I'm creating a `MAKEFILE` to check if git is installed or not.

Here is my shell script:

```
GIT_VERSION="$(git --version)"

check_version:
    echo ${GIT_VERSION}
    if [[ "${GIT_VERSION}" =~ "git version"]]; then
        echo "Git is installed"
    else
       echo "Git is NOT installed"
    fi
```

When I run the command `make check_version` in vs code, I'm getting the following error:

```
echo ""

if [[ """" =~ "git version" ]]; then
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: * [check_version] Error 2
```

Comment: What do you expect the value of variable `GIT_VERSION` to be immediately after `GIT_VERSION="$(git --version)"`?  Check using `$(info GIT_VERSION=[$(GIT_VERSION)])` .  I suspect you want `GIT_VERSION=$(shell git --version)` .

Comment: @G.M. I'm getting ```GIT_VERSION=[""]``` and the same above error

Comment: Note that regex comparison `=~` is a bash enhancement as well.

Comment: Also, you can't use `$(git ...)` because `$(...)` is interpreted as a make function or variable.  If you want to pass `$`, which is a special character to make, to the shell you have to double it, so `$$(git ...)`